# What would be the build that give me the most movement speed?

Tags: league-of-legends

And I'm not talking about a viable build. Just a build that would make me go from one side of the map to the other the fastest.

What champion should I pick? With what masteries? With what items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can gave movement speed through 2 master abilities: [Initiator](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Initiator) (3%) and [Swiftness](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Swiftness) (4%).  Also, you can take [Summoner's Wrath](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Summoner%27s_Wrath) to improve your Sprint speed by 35%.

Obviously take [Ghost](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost) as your summoner.

You can rune 3 [movement speed quintessences](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_runes#Swiftness) for an addition 4.5% move speed.

[Boots of Mobility](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Boots_of_Mobility) offer the largest boost, of +5 when out of combat.  Add in 5 [Phantom Dancers](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom_Dancer) for an additional 60% movespeed.

Finally, while it's not sustained, [Rammus' Powerball](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rammus_the_Armordillo) move reaches the highest speed of any champion.  For sustained burst speed, such as across the map, [Master Yi's Higlander](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Yi_the_Wuju_Bladesman) is better.

Comment: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLJvHCtlVVY). Don't forget Summoner's Resolve for Revive!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could find some videos on Youtube with speed records using :

- Rammus
- Boots of mobility + 5 phantom dancers
- Ghost
- Masteries and Runes
- Zilean + Sivir + Kayle + Nunu
- One of them Having shurelya's reverie ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Any champion with speed boost (kennen, zilean) or with gap closer (Lee Sin, Jax) so you can jump over walls with help of wards.

What items? Shurelya's reverie and youmuu's ghostblade both give nice movement speed, but I personally like Shurely's more.

What masteries? Intiator on defense and swiftness on utility give both movement speed. Also I have seen many people use movement speed runes. Janna's passive also gives 3% movement speed.

Answer (score 0):

Zephyr gives +10% move speed as opposed to Phantom Dancer's 5%

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that worked for me was 
Master Yi
ULT
TALISMAN
YOUMUS
3 ZEPHYR
MOBY BOOTS HOMEGUARD

all at the same time and
GHOST
REVIVE

Answer (score -1):

Take Hecarim with GHOST and REVIVE, buy mobo' with homeguard, Talisman, 3 Zehpyrs and the upgrade of qss and you should be fine

Answer (score -2):

buy 5 zepher and one boot of mobilty with homeguard enchantment

Comment: This only answers a third of the question. What about runes and champion?